# "must not be" or "must not have been"?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

I'm wondering "must not be" or "must not have been" should be used in the following:

> This defamatory letter must not have been written by John / must not be written by John. He's the kindest guy I've known.

Comment: "The letter _cannot_ have been written by John" would be more natural.

Comment: Thank you. Is it correct to say "The letter cannot be written by John"i n this scenario?

Comment: It's possible, but I think the past tense is more idiomatic. The sense is "It isn't possible that John wrote this letter."

Comment: Both versions are fine, and in any but the most contrived contexts, ***mean exactly the same thing***. Just as *John **couldn't** have done it* and *John **can't** have done it*, for example, are usually equivalent and interchangeable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["can't" versus "couldn't", what is the difference?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38140/cant-versus-couldnt-what-is-the-difference) But see also [How should I use 'must' in past tense?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51533/how-should-i-use-must-in-past-tense) and similar questions, because "must" is a funny verb when it comes to the past tense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question is not about "can't" vs. "couldn't." It's about whether to use adjectival passives or dynamic passives. In the former case, "must not be" seems okay. In the latter, "must not have been" seems preferable,

Answer (score 0):

I say that “must not be” should be used in the sentence.